# Implementing maps (use pin to show current position) in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an app in which i have to my current location on google maps by means of some pin means i want to show **pin on my current location**.Any help regarding this will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html Get current location and show it on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you required is called **map overlays**.

See below link, you will get an idea to display your image(pin) on map at current location.

[Android Google Maps Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html)

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answere and +1 for help

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html
u can see how the image is placed on the map